# How to connect and download file from FTP server in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sftp

Im already try SSH plugin, in debug mode app is running without error but when i try in release mode error is throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.jce.Random, anyone know how to fix this problem or different way to connect SFTP?

Comment: Same problem, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

What I did is that I looked for the location of the package file in my flutter dependencies file and got the directory containing the package. I navigated my way to it in explorer then went `android/build.gradle` and changed the `compileSdkVersion` to 28 instead of 27. Rebuild the app into release again. It should work